# Regex for allow some special characters but not allowing spaces in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am wrote the following regex for accepting one lowercase and one uppercase letter , one digit and one special character(!@#$%).

```
/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%]).*$/
```

But the above regex accepts space also . How to restrict space using regex in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way here would be to just match `[^ ]*` instead of `.*` in your pattern:

```
/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[^ ]*$/
                                                      ^^^ change here
```

If by "space" you actually mean any whitespace character, then use `\S` instead:

```
/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])\S*$/
```

**Edit:**

If you instead want to restrict to only alphanumeric (uppercase or lowercase) along with a fixed set of symbols, then use this pattern:

```
/^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%]*$/
```

Comment: The above regex takes not specified special characters also like *,&,^,(,) ........

Comment: @durgasivakishoremopuru Well what is your exact requirement here?  What is the total set of characters which you want your regex to accept?  Note that I cannot figure that out just by looking at your lookaheads.  The lookaheads just tell me which _must_ be present, not what _can_ be present.

Comment: Eg:- Mncl@12345  =  true , Mncl@12345& = false , Mncl@12345^ = false

Comment: [My pattern is already covering your example](https://regex101.com/r/Kavkkf/1), so I don't know what the problem is `:~(`

Comment: In your patteren just enter * character at last it matches , but i want to allow only some special characters like !@#$%

Comment: You still haven't answered my question.  _Which_ characters are allowed in your pattern?

Comment: Contain 8 to 20 characters ,   
 Have at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number 
 Not include spaces, and contain only the following special characters ! @ # $ %

Comment: @durgasivakishoremopuru Check my latest update, maybe this is what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[^ ]*$
```